# Probability in choice experiments

Tags: probability, conjoint-analysis, choice-modeling

I just started to get into the theory of probability/choice experiments and there are some topics that I don't understand. Hope you can help me to get the hang of it.

Lets say the following situation is given:

The factor price has the following levels:

30 = -2 
25 = -1.25 
20 = -0.5 
15 =  0.5 
10 = 1.25 
5 = 2 <- this one is assumed

The probability that one would choose 5 over 30 is

exp(2)/(exp(2)+exp(-2)) = 0.982

Can anybody explain the formula exp(2)/(exp(2)+exp(-2)) = 0.982 more in detail?

---

Updated comment on 19.10 for follow up question.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This situation relates to the so called [softmax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function) function that assigns probabilities based on scores. Let the scores be $s_1,s_2,\dots,s_n$ any real numbers. The softmax calculates the probability of selection of $j$th item as
$$
p_j = \frac{\exp(\alpha s_j)}{\sum_{i=1}^n\exp(\alpha s_i)}
$$
where $\alpha$ is a positive real number. As $\alpha\to 0$, the selection is getting uniform (each item has the same probability). As $\alpha\to\infty$, the item with highest score gets probability $100\%$. Due to these facts, this is a soft maximization, paramterized by $\alpha$. For more details and the application of this concept, see also [Sutton & Barto 1998](http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~sutton/book/ebook/node17.html).

Comment: I try to apply the softmax function, but I am not sure if I do it the correct way. Based on my example I want to know the probability that one would chose 5 over 30. According to the softmax function I need to exp(2)/(exp(-2)+exp(-1.25)+exp(-0.5)+exp(0.5)+exp(1.25)+exp(2)). But the original function in my comment says exp(2)/(exp(2)+exp(-2)). I just sums up exp(2)+exp(-2) as divisor. Additionally I updated the original comment with an sample calculation. I assume this is not right calculated? Best regards